# postgress : SQLQuery : Week start and End date

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

How to find out start and end date of week when Event Date is known.

```
DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, eventDate)-1), eventDate) [WeekStart] 
DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, eventDate)), eventDate) [WeekEnd]
```

I've tried this approach but it gives error as

```
ERROR:  function datepart(unknown, timestamp without time zone) does not exist 
LINE 3:     DATEADD('dd', -(DATEPART('dw', eventDate)-1)
```

Can you please suggest what could be the query for postgres ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres, just use `date_trunc()`:

```
select date_trunc('week', eventDate),
       date_trunc('week', eventDate) + interval '1 week'
```

Your code is SQL Server syntax.